# getting input value in ajax from table - spring mvc

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to get input in ajax in which row edit button is clicked.But i always get input which in first row.
This is my html code:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id = "cardTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>expression</th>
                    <th>type</th>
                    <th>edit card</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <c:forEach var="card" items="${cards}">
                    <tr>

                        <td>${card.expression}</td>
                        <td>${card.cardType.name} <input id="card" name="card" type="hidden" value="${card.id }"></td>

                        <!--<td><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cardUpdate" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</Button></td>-->
                        <td><button onclick="addAttribute()" class="btn-primary">edit</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>

</table>
```

This is my ajax code:

```
function addAttribute() {
var card = $('#card').closest("tr").parent('td').find('input[name=name]').val();
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: contexPath + "/getUpdatableCard",
    data:"card=" + card,
    dataType:'json',
    contentType : "application/json",
    success:function(data) {
        $("#cardUpdate").modal("show");
        alert(data.id);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }
});
```

}

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple elements like this:

```
<input id="card" ...
```

Repeating an `id` is invalid HTML, so the behavior of this is technically undefined:

```
$('#card')
```

This *may* be browser-specific, but what appears to be happening here is that it's matching the *first* element with that `id`.  You'd need to use valid HTML and adjust the selector accordingly to match all of them.  Something like this:

```
<input class="card" ...
```

and

```
$('.card')
```

---

**However**, this isn't entirely necessary in the first place.  Because when you click your button, you only want the `input` *relative to that button*, so you don't want to select *all* of the `input` elements anyway.  (And even if you did, as soon as you called `.val()` you'd still resolve only to the first in the matched set.)

Essentially, I think you want something like this:

```
var card = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=name]').val();
```

That is, starting from `this` you traverse to the containing `<tr>` and then find the `input[name=name]` therein.  (Though I'm not seeing an `input[name=name]` in your code in the first place.  A typo perhaps?)

Comment: it should be 'input[name=card]'.thank you very much :) it works)